# How do I run systemctl command on root mount

Tags: systemd

On my Arch systemd install, the name of the root mount unit is `-.mount`. (It is not listed in `/etc/fstab`, rather, it get the details of the root mount for the kernel options specified in the boot manager.)

If I try run any systemctl command on this unit, e.g:

```
systemctl show -.mount
```

I get this error:

```
systemctl: invalid option -- '.'
```

It is confusing the unit name for a option argument. How do I do this? Is there some why to escape the name so that it is not confused for a option argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By commonly used rules of specifying command-line parameters, a dash in front of an argument makes it interpreted as a short option.

*More precisely, `-.mount` is interpreted as 6 consecutive options, equivalent to: `-. -m -o -u -n -t`.*

To avoid this, place two dashes (`--`) in front of an argument:

```
systemctl show -- -.mount
```

This will ignore any option parsing in the remainder of the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Mountpoint paths can be used to specify a `.mount`-type unit in any subcommand of `systemctl`, so you can do

```
systemctl show /
```

Comment: Beautiful. I did not know of this possibility. However, I'd rephrase a bit (see suggested edit)...